# Can I Create a Folder in Sharepoint Automatically using workflow?

Tags: folder

I want the content of the "Current Month" Folder to automatically move into a newly created folder titled after the month (i.e. "January 2016") once we get into February 2016.

Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

I would rename the folder instead of moving the documents.

- Using a workflow check if the date is the 1st of the month.
- If yes rename folder to current month (have a calculated column to get the month of creation set name to calculated month name).
- Then create new item of type folder in your library.
- Run this workflow as a retention policy (settings>information management>retention.) Must be a 2010 workflow to use retention.

Comment: can this work for SharePoint 2013 enterprise version? Also, where can I get good tutorials on workflow... what I see are limited to alerts but I want to get some intermediate experience in using workflow.

Comment: @AlfatahKader To get started on workflows I recommend sharepoint deisgner (or you can code them in C# if you have coding experience). Once you have SPD it is pretty straight forwards to create a workflow and there are many online tutorials you can find through google. And yes should work fine in enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

For workflow being able to create folders, you need to **assign the folder content type** to the list and then create new item from workflow using **folder content type**.

### Add folder content type in list

1. Open the list in an internet browser. There will be an option bar at the top.
2. Select "List" and choose "List Settings" in the new ribbon.
3. Click on "Advanced Settings", activate the option "Enable management of content types" and click on "OK".
4. Back to the list settings.
5. Click on "Add from existing content types".
6. In the new page, select "Folder Content Type" from the dropdown menu.
7. Add the content type named "Folder" to the list content types by selecting it and clicking on the arrow pointing to the right.
8. Click on "OK" to save the new assignment.

### Create folder using workflow

1. To create a folder, choose the action "Create a list item".
2. Click on action to fill more information.
3. Choose the list where the folder shall be added from the dropdown field.
4. If your list has multiple content types, a field to assign a value to, will automatically be added. It is called "Content Type ID". If it is not present, click on "Add" to add this field.
5. Select "folder" from dropdown.
6. Set title field for folder name.

Comment: I have my documents in a Document Library. These are word files different users update. At the end of the month, I would like them to be inside a folder. The solution above for List - does it have a parallel solution for Document Library? If not, do you suggest that I move these documents and put them in a List?

Comment: You can try this solution in document library also.. This should work in document library also.

Comment: I will try it this week. I appreciate the answer